# more ways to add a static block in a page, but what is the best way?

Tags: magento, static, block

i would like to know what is the best way to insert the created static block in to my page. 
f.i. the second block in the left column of bokszakkenstore.nl
i inserted that block by adding it in catalog.xml
but now i also see that you can add it by editing the left-col.phtml or page.xml or page.phtml.

so what is the best way and why?

here's how i did it in catalog.xml with my static block left_banner

left_banner

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The quickest way is like this:

```
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('block_identifier')->toHtml(); ?>
```

But you can also create it as an XML block in your layouts folder and bring it out in the usual way (I prefer this when using custom themes):

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('block_identifier') ?>
```